# How to add Admob to unity Game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Okay i've pretty much been looking throug pages and pages of tutorials, plugins, etc for admobs to work with unity and there just not working!

when i use this tutorial 'http://wewritecode.com/2014/04/13/setting-admob-android-ios-unity/' 
All i get it ERROR 'Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Users/***/Documents/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624/sdk\tools\zipalign.exe', CommandLine='4 "C:\Users***\Documents\Unity Dev\swine2\Temp/StagingArea/Package_unaligned.apk" "C:\Users\Max\Documents\Unity Dev\swine2\Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'

same thing happens when i use this tutorial 'http://fastegggames.com/blog/2014/3/25/tutorial-setting-up-google-play-services-plugin-for-unity'

My question is: Does anybody know why im getting the error when trying to build and run my game to my android device?

Addition: If anybody can point me to a tutorial that works, it would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Show us your code. Are you changing anything from the tutorials?

Comment: You should really mark people's answers as correct. You've asked 7 questions and marked non as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Google official AdMob Plugin from here - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins

And documentation here - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity

I have seen that its way simpler and easy using the official Google AdMob plugin for unity rather than others.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this [Admob Unity Plugin](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob)

It is really simple,import the admobplugin.unitypackage,and then code as following

```
using admob;
...
Admob.Instance().initAdmob("admob banner id", "admob interstitial id");//admob id with format ca-app-pub-2796046890663330/756767388
Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative(AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0);
```

and then add this code to main camera or other object on stage